# Cannot bootload again after changing the board?

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, bootloader, avrdude

We are so tired and would like to get help with this. We are trying to bootload using the arduino Uno.

We have an `atmega 328p` smd , that we are trying to bootload. We have connected all the right pins, added to the boards.txt the  `"Atmega328 on a breadboard(8mhz internal clock)"`.

Then I have chosen from the "board" menu, this option (internal clock), and uploaded the program. **it worked** .

Later, I wanted to try and bootload for external clock so I chose from the boards menu the `pro mini with 5v board.`(is it wrong?)

Not only that I got an error, now, **I can't bootload the internal clock again** !!

Why can't we bootload again? Did we damage something? Can it be reset again?
How can you bootload for external 16Mhz ??

error :

```
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again
```

Comment: When burnt the `Pro Mini` bootloader did it work?

Comment: **Check This out my problem have been solved.**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYi815scN2A&ab_channel=LearnItAllAcademy

Comment: Please check capacitor value it must be in between 18pF to 20pF(The capacitors used for crystal)

Answer (score 1):

> Not only that I got an error, now, I can't bootload the internal clock again !

You need an external clock source, such as a crystal and two capacitors. Once you switch the fuses to the external clock it won't work any more unless you have such a clock.

I have a [bootloader uploader](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11635) sketch that also provides a clock signal if you need it.